# md-ink-ripple does not read color value from controller.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

html:

```
<div md-ink-ripple="color"> </div>
```

angular controller:

```
$scope.color = "#ffff00";
```

it only accepts solid hash code as parameter. I cannot pass scope variable to it. what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use it with curly brackets

```
<div md-ink-ripple="{{color}}"> </div>
```

Comment: someone should give me downvote for this question. :( I actually was passing color via scope function and it was not working without binding expressions. why I have to use them here? I think `md-ink-ripple` is a directive that should read `$scope` keys normally like `ng-click="colorFn()"` but in here I have to use it like `md-ink-ripple="{{colorFn()}}"`